# Does accept() at server side unblock for each HTTPS request from client?

Tags: c, https, winsock, winsock2

I have a problem with making HTTPS requests from the client to the server.

My server is using Winsock with OpenSSL on top of the sockets, while my client is using WinHttp library. All these are done in C.

Below is a description of what happened (or how I understood it to be) at the server and client during a network communication:

At the server side, the application is blocked at accept() while waiting for connection to be made from the client. On the first HTTP request made by client using WinHttpSendRequest(), the accept() unblocks and creates a new thread. Then, accept() went into blocking state again until a new client connects to it.

In the thread at the server side, recv() receives the packet sent over by the client, then it sends over a response packet via send().

Upon receiving the response packet from server, WinHttpSendRequest() at the client side unblocks, before moving on to execute WinHttpReceiveResponse() and the rest of the code to read in the content of the response packet.

Meanwhile, recv() at the server side blocks until client sends over another request via WinHttpSendRequest(), and this goes on to and fro until the server sends a command to terminate the client.

This mechanism of using Winsock at the server side and WinHttp at the client side works for sending multiple HTTP requests from client to server over the same connection.

However, when I decided to add in a layer of encryption for this network communication, ie. client sends HTTPS instead of HTTP requests over, and server uses openSSL functions to receive and send packets (SSL_read() in replacement of recv() and SSL_write in replacement of send()), each time the client makes a WinHttpSendRequest(), accept() at the server side will unblock and return a new socket. In the previous scenario where encryption was not done and requests were HTTP, accept() at the server side will only unblock when it is the first request made by a new client; subsequent requests by the same client will be received through the blocking and unblocking of recv().

Just some things to note: For my client side, I have kept the handles for WinHttpOpen and WinHttpConnect open, while those of WinHttpOpenRequest and WinHttpSendRequest will be closed after each request and recreated for each new request. Also, packets received for both sides can be read properly after encryption (I know encryption was done as packets sniffed by Wireshark is unreadable).

I have been searching all over the internet to see if anyone has experienced the same thing, but to no avail :( Is there anyone who can explain to me why this is happening?